# Geode Authentication implementation using TLS/SSL certificate

Tags: shiro, gemfire, geode, spring-data-gemfire, spring-boot-data-geode

I am trying to implement TLS based authentication, basically SSL certificate based authentication, when two-way SSL is enabled in Geode cluster. Authentication is performed based on certificate DN. Lets say client/peer node configured with two-way ssl of certificate "cn=example.com,ou=org,location=us", authentication and authorization should only be successful if "example.com" is valid cert and authorize accordingly. I see that Geode authentication implementation is based on security-username/password and security Manager Geode implementation does not provide better way to access connection peer certificates. I was not able to find related documentation, any direction on this kind of requirement would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you may already be familiar based on the comments in your question above, I encourage you to first re-review the section on [SSL](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/114/managing/security/ssl_overview.html) in the [Security](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/114/managing/security/chapter_overview.html) chapter of Apache Geode's documentation. SSL would be a prerequisite for everything I am about to suggest below.

Apache Geode's Security implementation of Authentication (as well as Authorization) is based on Apache Geode's [`SecurityManager`](https://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/security/SecurityManager.html) interface as well as the [`AuthInitialize`](https://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/security/AuthInitialize.html) interface.

The `SecurityManager` is used on the server-side to authenticate clients (or additional peers joining the P2P cluster as a member). An implementation of the `AuthInitialize` interface is used by clients (or other peers joining the P2P cluster as a member) to supply the credentials.

The supplied `SecurityManager` implementation is configured with the `[gemfire.]security-manager` property. The `AuthInitialize` implementation is configured with the `[gemfire.]security-client-auth-init` property (or the `[gemfire.]security-peer-auth-init` property).

While Apache Geode's documentation commonly refers to username/password-based authentication for Geode nodes (clients and peers), the fact of the matter is, the `Properties` returned by the (client-side) `AuthInitialize.getCredentials(..)` ([Javadoc](https://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/security/AuthInitialize.html#getCredentials-java.util.Properties-org.apache.geode.distributed.DistributedMember-boolean-)) method and processed on the server-side, `SecurityManager.authenticate(:Properties)` ([Javadoc](https://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/security/SecurityManager.html#authenticate-java.util.Properties-)) could contain the appropriate **certificate** and **evidence** as described (for example) [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19424-01/820-4811/gdzdg/index.html).

It is not uncommon for Password-based authentication to be used with Certificate-based authentication (both over SSL).

In which, case you could do the following. On the client-side:

```java
package example.app.geode.security.client.auth;

import org.apache.geode.security.AuthInitialize;

class CertificateBasedAuthInitialize implements AuthInitialize {

  public static CertificateBasedAuthInitialize create() {
    new CertificateBasedAuthInitialize();
  }

  public Properties getCredentials(Properties securityProperties, DistributedMember member, boolean isServer) {

    Properties credentials = new Properties(securityProperties);

    // Load PrivateKey from KeyStore using java.security API.
    PrivateKey privateKey = ...

    Certificate clientCertificate = privateKey.getCertificate();

    // Sign the some randomly generated data with the PrivateKey.
    Object signedEvidence = ...

    credentials.put("certificate", clientCertificate);
    credentials.put("evidence", signedEvidence);
    // optional...
    credentials.put(AuthInitialize.SECURITY_USERNAME, username);
    credentials.put(AuthInitialize.SECURITY_PASSWORD, password);

    return credentials;

  }
}
```

Then configure your client with:

```
# Spring Boot application.properties

spring.data.gemfire.security.client.authentication-initializer=\
  example.app.geode.security.client.auth.CertificateBasedAuthInitialize.create

...
```

The server-side, custom `SecurityManager` implementation would then use the credentials to authenticate the client.

```java
package example.app.geode.security.server.auth;

import org.apache.geode.security.SecurityManager;

class CertificateBasedSecurityManager implements SecurityManager {

  public Object authenticate(Properties securityProperties) {

    Certificate certificate = securityProperties.get("certificate");

    Objected signedEvidence = securityProperties.get("evidence");

    // verify the client's cert and use the PublicKey to verify the "evidence".
  } 
}
```

If the servers's in the Apache Geode cluster were configured and bootstrapped with Spring, then you would configure your custom `SecurityManager` implementation using:

```
# Spring Boot application.properties

spring.data.gemfire.security.manager.class-name=\
  example.app.geode.security.server.auth.CertificateBasedSecurityManager
```

If you used *Gfsh* to start the Locators and Servers in your cluster, then refer to Apache Geode's [documentation](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/114/tools_modules/lucene_integration.html) to configure properties on startup.

As you may also be aware (based on your tags), Apache Geode integrates with Apache Shiro. Unfortunately, I did not find any support in Apache Shiro for Certificate-based Authentication ([here](https://shiro.apache.org/authentication.html)), which introduces the concept of [`Realms`](https://shiro.apache.org/realm.html#Realm-RealmAuthentication) for *auth*, where the available `Realms` provided by Apache Shiro are [here](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.9.1/apidocs/) (you can see support for *ActiveDirectory*, JDBC, JNDI, LDAP, and text-based `Realms`).

Of course, you could also devise an implementation of Apache Geode's `SecurityManager` interface along with the `AuthInitialize` interface, integrated with Spring Security and follow the general advice in [Baeldung's blog post](https://www.baeldung.com/x-509-authentication-in-spring-security).

Hopefully this gives you enough to think about and some ideas on how to go about implementing Certificate-based Authentication between clients and servers (and peers?) in your [Spring] Apache Geode application/cluster.

Comment: DISCLAIMER: I have not tried nor tested this configuration arrangement myself, so your mileage may vary. However, this would essentially be the basic setup and idea.